# CUDA - invalid device function, how to know [architecture, code]?

Tags: cuda

I am getting the following error when running the default generated kernel when creating a CUDA project in VS Community:

```
addKernel launch failed: invalid device function
addWithCuda failed!
```

I searched for how to solve it, and found out that have to change the `Project->Properties->CUDA C/C++->Device->Code Generation`(default values for [architecture, code] are `compute_20,sm_20`), but I couldn't find the values needed for my graphic card (GeForce 8400 GS)

Is there any list on the net for the [architecture, code]  or is it possible to get them by any command?

Comment: GeForce 8400 GS is only Compute Capability 1.1. For future reference note that there are quite a few easily searchable lists with this info for all available CUDA GPU boards - make sure you include the term "Compute Capability" in your Google search,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The numeric value in `compute_XX` and `sm_XX` are the Compute Capability (CC) for your CUDA device.

You can lookup this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Supported_GPUs for a (maybe not complete) list of GPUs and there corresponding CC.

Your quite old 8400 GS (when I remember correctly) hosts a G86 chip which supports CC 1.1.

So you have to change to `compute_11,sm_11`

`

Comment: NVIDIA maintains what should be a fairly complete list [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus).

Comment: It seems nvidia has removed everything prior to CC 2.0 from this list, or do I just don't see it?

Comment: The lowest they are 2.0, more reason to ask when I am using a not so good GPU, and I think I saw that page once, but it did not appear my GPU.