# How to detect NVIDIA CUDA Architecture

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvcc

When compiling CUDA code with the NVCC compiler you typically (AFAIK) need to specify the PTX architecture with `-arch=compute_35` or `-arch=sm_35` but there are multiple architectures.  I would like to make my code as portable as possible so that a configure script could detect what architecture to use and pass the argument to the NVCC compiler.

This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451859/cuda-invalid-device-function-how-to-know-architecture-code) answers where I could find it online but I would prefer to have a script so a downstream user could just install my program without needing to know the specific architecture of their GPU.

Comment: When do you want to detect which CUDA architecture? Do you want to use the detected architecture for a build which is customized for the hardware it is currently executing on? Are you aware that you can compile for multiple architectures?

Comment: I was not aware you could compile for multiple architectures.  Would it be efficient to just compile for all possible architecture?  I'm trying to find a balance between absolute performance and portability.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599189/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-multiple-arch-flags-in-nvidias-nvcc-compiler): " An executable can contain multiple versions of SASS and/or PTX, and there is a runtime loader mechanism that will pick appropriate versions based on the GPU actually being used."

Comment: Thanks, that question does appear to answer my own.  It appears the only real drawback is some compile time.  I will mark my question as a duplicate as it asks a slightly different question than the other (although the answer is provided).  Thank you.